# Android : Maintaining Database update in ListView Automatically

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I am populating `ListView` with data from database . To bind data i'm using a `CursorAdapter` My list view looks like this

[image]

And my db will get updated through `web service` on every five seconds so when ever the db get updated i need to reflect the change on my list view . As you see my first 2 items in `ListView` row is directly bind with the columns in db it will get automatically updated. But other items are calculated in user side. so how will other items can be updated ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling Adapter_Object.notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: i think this will not help. because i don't know when will the db get updated.. so how can i notify it ??

Comment: You must have code that updates your database, after doing that you can call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: actually its done by an sdk. its not giving any call back to ui